# Prevent Webpack from removing jQuery functions?

Tags: javascript, webpack

When my JS file is bundled with (WebPack Version 5), it removes my functions. My config is as follows:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: './Scripts/main.js'

    },
    output: {
        publicPath: "/js/",
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/wwwroot/js/'),
        filename: 'main.build.js'
    }
};
```

and I want to compress and bundle this file:

```
function GetModal(e) {
    /*Modal code...*/
}


setTimeout(function () {
    if ($('div.modalRequest').length > 0) {
        $('div.modalRequest').empty();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/RequestCall/TextEditorRequestContact',
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            content: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                $('div.modalRequest').append(data);
            }
        });

    }
}, 100);


$(function () {
    setInterval(function () { $("#btnsliders").click().fadeIn() }, 5000);
})
```

and the output file is like this

```
setTimeout((function() {
    $("div.modalRequest").length > 0 && ($("div.modalRequest").empty(), $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/RequestCall/TextEditorRequestContact",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        content: "json",
        success: function(t) {
            $("div.modalRequest").append(t)
        }
    }))
}), 100), $((function() {
    setInterval((function() {
        $("#btnsliders").click().fadeIn()
    }), 5e3)
}));
```

In this example, `GetModal` function is removed
Does anyone know why WebPack removes the function?
Is there a way can I prevent this?

Comment: Where are you using `getModal`? Looks to me like Webpack is removing dead code, as it should.

Comment: I use```  getModal ``` in ajax call, is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: I do not understand why you try to wrap the `setInterval` in a `document ready` event handler with this: `}), 100), $((function() {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In webpack.config.js, tell Webpack not to minimize your code

```
optimization: {
    minimize: false
  }
```

This will prevent Webpack from removing your GetModal function.

Comment: thanks, it worked. but why in minimization it remove function and doesn`t remove the reset?

Comment: During minimization, GetModal is removed because it is not used anywhere.

Comment: I have a new problem. ```GetModal``` doesnt delete but I cant call it with ```onclick="GetModal(this)"``` . i reference it in my HTML page but it shows this error ```Uncaught ReferenceError: GetModal is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):39)``` what should I do?

Comment: You can turn your GetModal function into a global function, by assigning it to the window object. It will work. Normally you would bundle all your logic with webpack, no need for global variables.
     
     `window.GetModal = function GetModal(e) {};`